# Does cutting the covering of subwoofer wire affect the sound quality?

Tags: wire, speakers, sound, electrical, music

I have Sony 5.1 channel sound system. There is some cut on covering of subwoofer wire. The copper wire is not affected at all. So, I am curious to know whether it will leak the passage of sound and hence, the sound quality will be affected or not?

Is there any disadvantage of it?

Comment: What Spehro says. There are people who will try to tell you otherwise :-(. The wire will work as well as it ever did. If you added a pool of grounded salty water where copper is visible it MAY make a difference, but all normal circumstances will be good.

Comment: It’s just a 2 mm cut in covering, should I fix it? Or is it ok? I have heard the sound and I don’t feel any difference in sound..

Comment: It should not matter at all. If you were worried about the look you could add tape or sleeving, but otherwise it should be fine as it is.

Comment: Lookwise it is not seen and wires are behind the TV Top table so lookwise no issue, I was worried about long term

Comment: And thanks for your all answers and help. I really came to know new thing in Electrical engineering. Earlier I was thinking that covering around the wires are like a water pipe, but in electrical wiring, I came to know that it is just a covering to avoid electric mixup with other wires, passage will flow same way either with covering or no covering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I'm tempted to state there's some special effect from the insulation capacitance and characteristic impedance that only the golden-ear audiophile can hear (a stunning difference!), no there is **no** measurable direct effect from that bit of insulation being there or not. The insulation keeps the wire from shorting to the other wire or to ground.

You can wrap some electrical tape around the bare spot and get on with your life. Heat shrink tubing might be a bit more attractive, but the kind of insulation used for speaker wire is sometimes very low melting point so you might further damage the wire with the heat gun.

Comment: Got it Spehro. Accepted & upvoted..!!